# common point on the three lines......

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Actually, I am dealing with a problem in barycentric coordinates
I got the equations of three lines as[image]

I know that these three lines sharing a common point, I know if I prove their det is zero, they are concurrent.

here the problem is to prove det is zero,

my question is there any shorter way to prove that det is zero, or is there any online tool which is useful in proving this, if so please share.

and also how should I find a common point on these lines which is in the form of (x:y:z)

please share the steps to get it or any online tool for finding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Frankly, I'd throw it into Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Really then can we find the solution like(x,y,z) from it, if so please share the ans,

Comment: I don't think wolfy like long queries.  Use a proper CAS instead

Comment: O then how to get the solution

Comment: Does $s$ have any relation to $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @amd: I think that is implicitly understood, when dealing with triangles in Euclidean geometry, that $s$ is the semiperimeter $(a+b+c)/2$.  Indeed, the determinant contains a factor $abcs(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(2s-a-b-c)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command in [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), you can use other CAS if you want:

```
s: (a+b+c)/2;
M: matrix(
[(b-c)*(2*s^3-2*s^2*a+s*(a^2-2*b*c)+a*b*c),
-a*(s-c)*(2*s^2-2*s*b+b^2),
a*(s-b)*(2*s^2-2*s*c+c^2)],
[b*(s-c)*(2*s^2-2*s*a+a^2),
(c-a)*(2*s^3-2*s^2*b+s*(b^2-2*c*a)+a*b*c),
-b*(s-a)*(2*s^2-2*s*c+c^2)],
[-c*(s-b)*(2*s^2-2*s*a+a^2),
c*(s-a)*(2*s^2-2*s*b+b^2),
(a-b)*(2*s^3-2*s^2*c+s*(c^2-2*a*b)+a*b*c)]
);
ratexpand(determinant(M));
```

(or use `factor` instead of `ratexpand`), which indeed shows the determinant is $0$.

You can also use `eigenvalues(M);` to see that there is indeed an eigenvalue $0$ of multiplicity $1$.  To find the eigenspace, use `eigenvectors(M);`, which we are only interested in the last part of the output (the full output is `[[[eigenvalues],[multiplicities]],[eigenvectors]]`)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\
{{bc^3+\left(ab-b^2\right)c^2+\left(-b^3+4ab^2+a^2b
 \right)c+b^4-ab^3-a^2b^2+a^3b}\over{ac^3+\left(ab-a^2
 \right)c^2+\left(ab^2+4a^2b-a^3\right)c+ab^3-a^2b^2-a^
 3b+a^4}}\\
{{c^4+\left(-b-a\right)c^3+\left(-b^2+4ab-a^2
 \right)c^2+\left(b^3+ab^2+a^2b+a^3\right)c}\over{ac^3+
 \left(ab-a^2\right)c^2+\left(ab^2+4a^2b-a^3\right)c+ab
 ^3-a^2b^2-a^3b+a^4}} \end{bmatrix}
$$
(OK, maxima doesn't really output like this, but you get the idea).  So clearing denominator $$x=a\left(\sum_{cyc}a^2(a-b-c)+2bc(b+c)+4abc\right)$$ and cyclic permute for $y,z$:

```
factor(M . columnvector([
a*(c^3+b*c^2-a*c^2+b^2*c+4*a*b*c-a^2*c+b^3-a*b^2-a^2*b+a^3),  
b*(c^3-b*c^2+a*c^2-b^2*c+4*a*b*c+a^2*c+b^3-a*b^2-a^2*b+a^3),  
c*(c^3-b*c^2-a*c^2-b^2*c+4*a*b*c-a^2*c+b^3+a*b^2+a^2*b+a^3)
]));
```

gives the output $[0,0,0]$.

**Edit**: correct factor of $2$, the expression is now much uglier.

Comment: No no (a, b, c)  is not satisfying the equations, so there is another  solution. And we need  non trival solution.

Comment: No no, I am sorry,  once u please check a, b, c are not satisfying the equations

Comment: No u typed the equation wrong

Comment: U typed (b-c)*(2*s^3-2*s^2*a+s*(a^2-b*c)+a*b*c).....

Comment: Actually (b-c)*(2*s^3-2*s^2*a+s*(a^2-2b*c)+a*b*c).....

Comment: corrected, it is ugly

Comment: s ugly but  nice.... thank you